# Using your own custom made classes to do a job for you

Tags: java, class, input, int

I am working on a Java application for my college class, and at one point in the program I am to ask the user to input an integer. I could just have the user input an integer, and if there is a problem, Like them putting in "abcdefg", I could just have a try/catch statement with a loop. But a while back I created a custom class that takes care of this problem by itself called`InputValidator`. It has a built in scanner and takes care of basically everything (checking to make sure it was actually an int, double, etc..) and in the main class you can simply set a value equal to one of the getter methods to make sure it is actually a valid input.

What I'm wondering is, do you think it would be considered "Lazy" of me by my professor, intuitive, or just unnecessary? This class could be useful for many things, but could also be considered "Wasting memory" (it also checks for double, and I in the program it just checks an int). I would like to use it, but I want to make sure this is a legitimate thing to do when it comes to programming in the classroom. Thank you in advance.

Comment: C/C++ programmers will tell you you're wasting memory and your design is inefficient. Java programmers will tell you you're a brilliant object oriented programmer. I personally like it.

Comment: haha ok makes sense. So that's why they say. All hail to the object oriented god.

Comment: As a Java programmer "you you're a brilliant object oriented programmer" :-p. Well how much memory can you wasted for that. int, double ... and what else?

Comment: If your teacher wants you to reinvent the wheel in every assignment: he is nuts!

Comment: Toss some useless marker-interfaces on there and you can be a Java Enterprise expert too.

Comment: @NawaMan Yes, it is a very small amount of memory wasted. But, memory is memory, and no matter how small it is it's not being used, so it is completely useless.

Comment: Normally that kind of usage is not considered a waste of memory... I don't know about C++/C but I can't really imagine anyone saying using a Class with some extra functionality is a waste. That being said academic assignments have some other goals that may be circumnavigated by using existing classes. So it's dependent on your judgment whether to reinvent the wheel or use someone else's wheels... But in this instance since you have written the class yourself there's no problem with using it, unless your professor is descendant from the mad hatter :-D

Comment: @DillonBurton That kind of thinking is only useful in embedded and mobile programming with small amount of memory available.

Comment: @DillonBurton the alternative is to split the already existing (assumed tested or used) into many class one for each type which can be good too. But unless you play to have many validators and your memory is really low. I don't think it is worth the effort.

Comment: @NewMan Actually, I really like the idea. Then I could still have all of my ready-to-go classes, just more of them that do more specific things. Then maybe instead of wasting memory in my program I would just be wasting it on my computer ;)

Comment: @Affe: As a Java enterprise programmer, i find that insulting. Useless marker interfaces are so '90s. We use useless marker *annotations* now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used my own classes for validating input as well. I don't see it as a problem, it reduces the code you need to write elsewhere and you can let the class do the job for you. Your professor shouldn't mind because he can clearly see you understand validating input.

[Here](http://computersciencecs.blogspot.dk/2012/12/java-input-checking.html) you can see the class I use.

Comment: Nice! I took a look at it and it seems like it could be very useful in certain situations. I find it so fascinating to see the different ways programmers go about solving the same problem.

Comment: Thank you. There sure are many different ways to solve the same problem. Everyone has so dramatically different styles. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have your custom class any time. But the thing that need to be considered is that why do u want to create your own code when there is already a Best Practice implementation available.

Java focuses more on code reuse. So in java world if there is a default method provided by some api, its always a good practice to use that because that api will provide the Best Practice implementation, which we may not achieve while writing our own code, and the those classes will be well tested. So there is a less chances for failure.

Definitely you wont be considered as "Lazy" for using the default methods in java api

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are valid in my eyes as a C++ and Java developer.
If I would have written the code in Java the try catch method seems reasonable and simplistic.

In C++ this would be problematic due to explicit casting.

If this is a pure Java class the I would think that the try catch would be sufficient and clean.